# Put a table into another table with repeated primary keys

Tags: database, entity-relationship

Turns out I have these three tables:

Recipes: id(primary key), name, time, difficulty, description, photo_url, amount_pax

Recipe_type: id(primary key), name

Ingredients: id(primary key), name

In my exercise the three tables have to be yes or yes.

I need to put the type of recipe and the ingredients in the recipe table but I don't know how to do it because I could put the id_type_recipe and the id_ingredients as a foreign key but the problem is that in several recipes said id can be repeated because if tomato has the id 1 in another recipe there may be tomato and this is not feasible because they are primary keys in another table that cannot be repeated... how could I put the type of recipe and ingredients in the recipe table?

I attach my E-R diagram.

[image]

I started by entering the ingredient id and the recipe type id but I realized that they were going to be repeated and this is not possible as they are primary keys in other tables.

Comment: Tomato will only show up once in `Ingrediente`. However, `utiliza` will become a linking table, that will include multiple entries with tomato, each one belonging to a different `Receta`.

Answer (score 0):

To handle `Recipe_Type` you can add `Recipe_TypeId` as an additional column to the `Recipes` table.

But for `Ingredients`, expecting each `Recipe` may need several `Ingredients` (of different quantities) **you will need an additional table**.

Let's say you have a Recipes for Tomato Soup and Chicken Noodle Soup with **Recipes** records like this:

| ID | Name | Time | Difficulty | Description | Photo_url | amount_pax | Recipe_Type_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tomato Soup | 3:00 | 1 | Take tomatos... | http://... | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | Chicken Noodle Soup | 20:00 | 2 | Cook Chic... | http://... | 4 | 1 |

and a **Recipe_type** like this:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Soup |

And **Ingredients** like this:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Tomatoes |
| 2 | Milk |
| 3 | Salt |
| 4 | Chicken |
| 5 | Water |
| 6 | Noodles |

Now you also need an *intersection table* (named, say **RecipeIngredient**) that would look something like this:

| RecipeID | IngredientID | Qty | Measure |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 8 | Each |
| 1 | 2 | 1.5 | Cups |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | Tsp |
| 1 | 5 | 1.5 | Cups |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | Tsp |
| 2 | 4 | 2 | Lbs |
| 2 | 5 | 4 | Cups |
| 2 | 6 | 1 | Lbs |

This new table will have a **compound key** like this: `(RecipeID, IngredientID)`

Comment: I would not have the linking table have a compound key, but have a primary key I'd of its own.  Imagine a recipe that uses 1T flour in one step and 2c flour in a different step